# Cypher query results unexpectedely affected by "WITH" statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher, with-statement

As part of a larger query, I am trying to select `PRODUCT`s that have a relationship to more than one `SKU`. I subsequently want to delete these relationships and perform other modifications not included here for the sake of simplicity.

I was surprised to find that while the following query returns a single node:

```
MATCH (p:PRODUCT)-[p_s_rel:PRODUCT_SKU]->(s:SKU)
WITH s, p, count(s) AS sCount
WHERE sCount> 1 AND id(s) IN [9220, 9201]
RETURN s
```

adding the relationships p_s_rel in the `WITH` clause changes the result and returns no nodes:

```
MATCH (p:PRODUCT)-[p_s_rel:PRODUCT_SKU]->(s:SKU)
WITH s, p, p_s_rel, count(s) AS sCount
WHERE sCount> 1 AND id(s) IN [9220, 9201]
RETURN s
```

Based on the documentation for `WITH`, I didn't expect this behavior. Is it not possible to specify relationship identifiers in the `WITH` clause?

If that's the case, how can I delete the `p_s_rel` relationships in my example?

Edit: This is on version 2.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the first query is doing what you think that it is? In your query if sCount > 1 then I think that means you have more than one relationship between p and some `SKU` (i.e multiple relationships between the same nodes). If your `WITH` statement were `WITH p, count(s) AS sCount` then you would be matching a single Product with multiple SKUs.

By executing `WITH s, p, count(s) AS sCount` you are saying *carry the currently matched SKU, the currently matched PRODUCT and the count of PRODUCT_SKU relationships between them*, whereas `WITH p, count(s) AS sCount` would be taken to mean *carry the currently matched PRODUCT and the count of all PRODUCT_SKU relationships that it has*.

In your second query, by including p_s_rel in your `WITH` clause you will be propagating only a single row with each result - as there will only ever be one distinct p_s_rel to carry forward in each match (a relationship only has one start node, and one end node). This means that sCount will never be greater than 1 - hence your empty resultset. i.e you are saying *carry the currently matched SKU, the currently matched PRODUCT, the current realtionship between those two nodes and the count of the end nodes on that relationship* (1).

If you want to carry the relationships forward you could use `COLLECT`, or, as you are going to be restricting your resultset by SKU, maybe you would be better off matching those first:

```
MATCH (s1:SKU), (s2:SKU)
WHERE ID(s1) = 9220 AND ID(s2) = 9201
WITH s1, s2
MATCH (s1)<-[r1:PRODUCT_SKU]-(p:PRODUCT)-[r2:PRODUCT_SKU]->(s2)
DELETE r1, r2,
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation makes perfect sense, my initial query was indeed incorrectly picking up `SKU`s with more than one relationship to a `PRODUCT`.

Building on your suggested query, is there an easy way to generalize it to more than 2 SKU ids? I had only included 2 to simplify the code, but the actual use case is with dozens of skus.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053509/neo4j-sum-relationship-properties-where-node-properties-equal-value-a-and-value/27062748#27062748 if you have multiple relationships between the same nodes, you'll need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT s))`